# CakePHP PDF reporting templates

Tags: pdf, cakephp

Do you have any idea on how to generate report templates for CakePHP Applications, like the ones you can use on [Dolibarr](http://www.dolibarr.org/) project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Dolibarr, but I hand code pdf templates for invoices etc using the fpdf helper. It's very good, but very hands on.

Answer (score 2):

i'm a dolibarr expert and it based on TCPDF
https://tcpdf.org/
also i have already use it in some projects using CakePHP 
it's too simple to integrate than fpdf